# RadioButtonList Display in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have the following radiobuttonlist

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_payment_type" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_payment_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Cheque</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Cash</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The display shows the options one below the other.

How do I display all the options in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property [RepeatDirection](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_radiobuttonlist_repeatdirection.asp):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_payment_type" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection = "Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_payment_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
```